# Pyqt5 open child windows of class of another file *.py Pb

Tags: python, pyqt5

I tried to implement a child window into my MainWindow. 
My childwindow become a class of another file.

My problem is that the child is shown and immediately closed. 
I tried differents methods on your site or web, without success.

The main.py :

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QDialog, QLabel
from Luxmeter_Viewer import Ui_Luxmeter_Viewer


class mainClass(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        openDlgBtn = QPushButton("openDlg", self)
        openDlgBtn.clicked.connect(self.openChildDialog)
        openDlgBtn.move(50, 50)

        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 200, 200)
        self.show()

    def openChildDialog(self):
        MyLuxmeter_Viewer = Ui_Luxmeter_Viewer()
        MyLuxmeter_Viewer.createWindow()
        MyLuxmeter_Viewer.show()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mc = mainClass()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

My child file *.py

```
import os
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QInputDialog, QLineEdit, QFileDialog,QMessageBox

class Ui_Luxmeter_Viewer(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.parent = parent
        super(Ui_Luxmeter_Viewer, self).__init__()

    def createWindow(self):
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.setWindowTitle("Luxmeter Viewer")
        self.resize(1780, 960)



def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = Ui_Luxmeter_Viewer()
    MainWindow.createWindow()
    MainWindow.show()

    rc = app.exec_()
    sys.exit(rc)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Change `MyLuxmeter_Viewer` to  `self.MyLuxmeter_Viewer`

Comment: Thank you. 
I forget this detail :)